Conic Constraint on Pyomo Abstract Model
I'm trying to build a rotated conic constraint by using:
rotated_quadratic(model.u_r[k, r], model.u_r[k, s], [model.I_r_s[k, r, s], model.T_r_s[k, r, s]])


All Sets and Variables are well defined:
model.I_r_s = Var(model.K, model.R, model.R, domain= Reals)
model.T_r_s = Var(model.K, model.R, model.R, domain= Reals)
model.u_r = Var(model.K, model.R, domain=Reals)
model.K = Set(dimen=1)
model.R = Set(dimen=1)

And all necessary data is being loaded correctly, yet when trying to solve the problem i run into this issue:
File "C:\Users\elseb\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\core\kernel\conic.py", line 274, in __init__
    assert isinstance(self._r1, IVariable)

AssertionError

I have no idea how to solve this issue, i would appreciate any help.
I tried checking all declarations and data, both seem correct.
